# AWS Elastic Beanstalk: Avoid redownload of app's static files on EB app update by caching

Tags: caching, amazon-web-services, deployment, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Our project contains Multi-Gb amount of static files that application downloads from Amazon S3 during Elastic Beanstalk deploy process (using .ebextensions/*.config files), so deployment of a new server instance to a cluster and/or application version updates are taking really long, so we even needed to seriously increase deployment timeout.

That files are located inside of an application directory and, as EB rebuilds main app dir on app version update, deploy process redownloads all static files from S3 again to a newly created dir on every app update, increasing deployment time and generating unnecessary trafic spends.

Idea is to prevent this redownloads by holding a cached copy of static files outside of app dir and just synchronize it with s3 on deploy (in case if any of static files are changed or removed on S3) with:

```
aws s3 sync s3://bucket/staicfiles path/to/local/cached/staticfiles --delete
```

and then just move/copy files from this cached dir to a newly deployed dir.

1. Is there any other idea / best practice for preventing redownloads of static files on update?
2. Is there any Amazon Linux recommended directories for a user cached files that is not going to be affected by a system or deploy process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new AWS service called Elastic File System resolved this problems. It allows to mount single virtual disk drive to several instances and to have access to files. Works like a charm.

You can find more about how Elastic File System (AWS EFS) works here:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/how-it-works.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use [EBExtensions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions.html) to execute arbitrary commands during your deployment. What I would do is use a command there to run the S3 sync to a folder not attached to your application deploy path, as you suggest.

You can place these commands in a '.ebextensions' directory at the root of your app - EB will read that during the deployment, and execute any '*.config' files found within.

As for other methods - I'm not sure of your application structure/organization/etc., but are these assets (images, js, css, etc.) that could be served from the S3 bucket directly? Then you could offset the loads to the server entirely.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. - 1. we are using .ebextensions/*.config files already - that is how we are downloading files from s3 on deploy. - 2. No, we are serving images, js, css from Amazon CloudFront, those static files (that we need in app dir) are application related files.

Comment: Cool - thanks for the additional information. The majority of EB containers uses `/var/app/ondeck/` to build the application, and then flip to `/var/app/current` when flipping it to be the active version. Any other folder you want to run your S3 sync into (I'd suggest something like /opt or /srv) should be fine.